# Redirect 301 PDF with spaces

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

Can somebody please help me? I would like to redirect a PDF to a website.

The link is: http://www.nvtz-nieuwsbrief.nl/user/downloads/2014-11/NVTZ%20Congres%206%20nov%202014%20Presentatie%20Leon%20van%20Halder.pdf

And want to redirect to website.com/site.html

Is there a solution? I tried "" /s and many things without any good result.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*.pdf$ http://www.website.com/site.html [R=301,L]

Usage = These rules will redirect all urls with .pdf extension to http://www.website.com/site.html